Problem understanding what values $h(t)$ admit in optimizatiom problem
This is an example from V. M. Alekseev "Sbornik zadach po optimizatsii"

Example 1 (extremal exists and delivers
global extremum).

$\mathscr{I}(x(\cdot))=\int_0^1 \dot{x}^2 d t \rightarrow$ inf: $x(0)=0, x(1)=1$.
Euler-Layrange equation: $\bar{x}=0$.
General solution to Euler equation: $x=C_1 t+C_2$. Unique extremal: $\hat{x}=t$
The extremal in this situation delivered global minimum. In fact, let $x(\cdot) \in C^1([0,1]), x(0)=0, x(1)=1$. Then $h(\cdot)=x(\cdot)-\hat{x}(\cdot) \in C_0^1(\{0,1])=\left\{z(\cdot) \in C^1([0,1]) \mid
 z(0)=z(1)=0\right\}$



\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned} &
 \mathscr{I}(x(\cdot))=\mathscr{I}(\hat{x}(\cdot)+h(\cdot))=\int_0^1(1+\dot{h})^2
 d t=\int_0^1 d t+2 \int_0^1 \dot{h} d t+\int_0^1 \dot{h}^2 d t= \\
 &=\mathscr{I}(\widehat{x}(\cdot))+\int_0^1 \dot{h}^2 d t \geqslant
 \mathscr{I}(\widehat{x}(\cdot)) .\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

From $h(\cdot)=x(\cdot)-\hat{x}(\cdot) \in C_0^1(\{0,1])=\left\{z(\cdot) \in C^1([0,1]) \mid  z(0)=z(1)=0\right\}$ I dont understand why $h(0)=h(1)=0$ Why in those points and why equal to $0$
In a similar probem  $$\mathscr{I}(x(\cdot))=\int_0^1 \dot{x}^2 d t \rightarrow inf: x(0)=0, x(T_0)=\xi$$
Then
\begin{equation*}
\mathscr{I}(\hat{x}+h)-\mathscr{I}(\hat{x})=\int_0^{T_0}(\dot{\hat{x}}+\dot{h})^2 d t-\int_0^{T_0} \dot{\hat{x}}^2 d t=\int_0^{T_0}(2 \dot{\hat{x}} \dot{h}) d t+\int_0^{T_0} h^2 d t
\end{equation*}
I thoght that $h(t)$ also satiffies the limit conditions  $x(0)=0, x(T_0)=\xi$ so I wrote
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{T_0} 2 \frac{\xi}{T_{10}} \cdot \dot{h} d t=2 \frac{\xi}{T_0}\left[\left.h(t)\right|_0 ^{T_0}\right]=\frac{2\xi^2}{T_0} \geqslant 0 .
\end{equation*}
It seems the condition $h(t_0)=h(t_1)=0$ is very important, why equal tp 0 both

You should translate your problem, so that everyone can understand it!

@Kolakoski54 check. I did my best

This is just rewriting $\hat{x} = x + h$ so that $\hat{x}$ satisfies the boundary condition $\hat{x}(1)=1$. It's basically saying that we choose perturbations $x$ that don't mess up our boundary conditions
